# Store a UIImage to server with REST

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, uiimage

I use restful web server to store and retrieve data on mysql database in my server. with strings all work perfect.But What should I do with images ? should i store the image on database or should i send the image on the server with ftp and put the link of image on the database ?

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this would depend on a lot of things.  What your restful services do, what their interface is, how your server is configured, how the images are processed, how the images are returned by services, what your client does, etc...

One answer might be - you could uuencode or base64 encode your image and then send that string as the payload in your post method to your restful webservice.

Comment: As I understand it, I could encode my UIImage to transform it into string, send the string to the database and when I want it back I get the string and decodes it? if that's it sounds much easier than using FTP. you have an example please?

Comment: Your database may not be able to hold a large enough string - as usual, it depends on a lot of things.  You might want your server to decode the string and convert it back into an image which it then saves to a location on your server.  Then you just store a path to that file in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Both work, but I would recommend against using FTP. Consider uploading the data, and then using some scripts to save the file.

Storing images in a database can be a good thing in some scenarios and a bad thing in others. The big advantage is that you only have one system to worry about, the big disadvantage is that the database grows larger and has to do more work. Of course, let's not forget that databases are easier to distribute than files, since they often have built-in mechanisms for that.

Comment: thank you , I am beginning and I seek the easiest way. I think i will use database, no ftp